# Replicated Convolutional Bi-Directional LSTM implementation in Keras diverging

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

This is the model I am trying to replicate (more information in linked paper):

> In our models, we adopted one dropout layer between LSTM models and the first fully-connected layer and another dropout layer between the first fully-connected layer and the second fully-connected layer. Their masking probabilities are both set to 0.5.
>
> ...
>
> For our proposed CBLSTM, one-layer CNN is firstly designed, whose filter number, filter size and pooling size are set to 150, 10 and 5. Therefore, the shape of the raw sensory sequence is changed from 100 x 12 to 19 x 150 after CNN. Then, a two-layer bi-directional LSTM is built on top of the CNN.
> Backward and forward LSTMs share the same layer sizes as [150, 200]. Therefore, the output of the LSTM module is the concatenated vector of the representations learned by backward and forward LSTMs, and its dimensionality is 400. Then, before feeding the representation into the linear regression layer, two fully-connected layers with a size of [500, 600] are adopted. The nonlinearity activation functions in our proposed CBLSTM are all set to ReLu.

Source: Zhao, R., Yan, R., Wang, J., & Mao, K. (2017). Learning to monitor machine health with convolutional bi-directional LSTM networks. Sensors, 17(2), 273. [link to paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313115860_Learning_to_Monitor_Machine_Health_with_Convolutional_Bi-Directional_LSTM_Networks)

The input is 630 samples x 100 timesteps x 12 features.

How my model looks at the moment:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=150, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', input_shape=(100,12)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides=None, padding='valid'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True), merge_mode='concat'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(200, return_sequences=False), merge_mode='concat'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(600, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae'])
```

While the training loss steadily decreases per epoch, the validation set does not and diverges pretty quickly. This indicates that there is a mistake in my model which I have not yet been able to find. Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Side note: I am using the same data as input as the authors.

Comment: Can you show a plot of your loss / validation loss, just so we can see excactly what's going on?

Comment: Giving it more epochs seems to make it somewhat converge, however the result (MAE 20.34 for c6) is still very far from that of the authors (MAE 8.1 for c6). @VegardKT [Image of training loss](https://pasteboard.co/IdSfKhZ.png) for c6.